# How to handle if one of user's role (say teacher) have many other roles in rolify and cancancan gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cancancan, rolify

I'm making a rails app in which one of user's have a teacher role and a teacher can teach many classes also a class can have many teachers.
So how can i handle this in rolify and cancancan gem?
I'm using rolify and cancancan gem for user roles.

Comment: please share existing code to show what you tried and is not working at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a better solution would be to use a many to many relationship between teachers and classes. Using rolify helps you define multiple user roles and cancancan helps you define access permissions to these roles.